# getblockchaininfo returning excessive "soft fork" info

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

The blockchaininfo command is now returning a lot of "softfork" information.

Is there a way I can get other fields without the softfork blob?

Comment: Don't look at them? Or if you're using `bitcoin-cli`, use `jq` or even `grep` to filter them out?

Comment: @PieterWuille You know, Pieter, blockchaininfo is a very commonly used command. It makes sense to return a single screen of the most useful information. For most users, the key thing is to make sure that they are synced, which means comparing the block count to the headers. Scrolling this critical information off the screen with a lot of softfork verbiage is a nuisance. There should either be a switch to remove that information altogether or at least it should be distilled to a synopsis so that the printout stays on one page.

Comment: RPC calls are more intended to be machine readable than human readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jq` shell command to filter out the unwanted keys.

`$ ./bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo | jq 'del (.softforks)' | jq 'del (.bip9_softforks)'`

with as output:

```
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 485623,
  "headers": 485623,
  "bestblockhash": "000000000000000000772fa60c075c57b8ba2db277a84454e1f8e27c3c307b10",
  "difficulty": 922724699725.9628,
  "mediantime": 1505593445,
  "verificationprogress": 0.9999959396017668,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000008aeb8bb8310a6b50e24bb0",
  "pruned": false
}
```